# SafeAccessTokenHandle could not be found and WindowsIdentity does not exist in the context

Tags: c#, impersonation, .net-standard, ef-core-2.2

i'm trying to impersonate the current user when i launch my app (wpf) to create my db with a specific user.

i'm trying with this code:

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeAccessTokenHandle phToken);

        private SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle;

        public DbSet<ArchiveModelDb> Archives { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TagModelDb> Tags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MediaModelDb> Medias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserModelDb> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ConfigurationTable> Config { get; set; }

        public DbContextArchiving(DbContextOptions<DbContextArchiving> options) : base(options)
        {
            try
            {
                ConfigurationTable configurationTable;

                using (var context = Initialize.GetContext())
                {
                    configurationTable = context.Config.FirstOrDefault();
                }
                bool returnValue = LogonUser(configurationTable.UsernameArchiveUser, "ngroup.be", configurationTable.PasswordArchiveUser, 2, 0, out safeAccessTokenHandle);

                if (!returnValue)
                {
                    int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
                }

                WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(
                        safeAccessTokenHandle,
                        () =>
                        {
                           Database.Migrate();
                        }
                   );
                safeAccessTokenHandle.Close();
                safeAccessTokenHandle.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

i download the nugget package System.Security.Principal to WindowsIdentity and Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles for the token.

When i try with this solution i can't launch the app because i have a part of my code underline with error like in title.

I have try an other solution and a download the nugget package System.Security.Principal.Windows

With this package i can launch my app but i have an exception
=>

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Db.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Db.dll 
but was not handled in user code
Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 
'System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier 
spécifié est introuvable.
```

thanks for your answer

Comment: What kind of project are you creating? `SafeAccessTokenHandle` is not available in .NET Standard but it should be available in the `System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll` .NET Framework assembly and in .NET Core.

Comment: Oh sry i forgot this. It's a class librairy in .net standard. i have try with System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll but doesn't work and throw the exception

Comment: A chronic problem with .NETStandard class libraries is that their dependencies don't get copied into the EXE build directory.  So start there first, ensure that System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll is in fact present there.  Next, make sure there is in fact a point to building a .NETStandard library in the first place.  There won't be when you need advapi32.dll to get the job done.

Comment: Where can i check this? In my project? if yes, i have already look in bin/debug/netstandar2.0 and nothing. I have already try to add with ctrl+c/v so doesn't work